# Get drag and drop source and destination in qtreewidget

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt, qtreewidget

I have simple tree in QTreeWidget (I use pyqt, but I think it`s not important). When I move item in this tree I want to change database, so I want to get this item object, parent of this item before moving and parent of this item after moving. But i don`t understand how I can get them. qtreewidget doesn`t has special signal for drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for my situation. May be some one can be interested:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object): # automatically generated with pyuic5
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        ...
        self.recordsTree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self.centralWidget)
        ...

class CustomTree(object):
    def startDrag(self, actions):
        row = self.selectedItems()[0]
        self._prev_parent = row.parent().data(0, 0)
        self._what_move = row.data(0,0)
        return QTreeWidget.startDrag(self, actions)
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        row_index = self.indexAt(event.pos()).row()
        self._new_parent = self.topLevelItem(row_index).data(0, 0)
        my_custom_collback(self._prev_parent, self._what_move, self._new_parent)  # <- that what i needed
        return QTreeWidget.dropEvent(self, event)


class MainWindow(Ui_MainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, m):
        r = super(MainWindow, self).setupUi(m)
        self.recordsTree.startDrag = types.MethodType(CustomTree.startDrag, self.recordsTree)
        self.recordsTree.dropEvent = types.MethodType(CustomTree.dropEvent, self.recordsTree)
        return r
```

Comment: How about `_new_parent=self.itemAt(event.pos())`? So it works also for non-top-level parents.